# Configuration parameters in play! 1.X still valid in Play 2.1 application?

Tags: frameworks, playframework, settings, playframework-1.x, playframework-2.1

I would to know if all parameters defined to Play! 1.X still valid to Play! 2.1, because I cant found the same parameters in Play 2.1 documentation, like http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.3/configuration.

I was looking for session parameters to controls session timeout to my application.

anyone can help me ?

Comment: argh... NO, parameters defined in Play 1.x aren't valid in 2.x... probably somebody can help you, anyway ... you need to specify what are you missing...

Answer (score 0):

The session handling in 2.0 and 2.1 is a bit different, check out [the documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/ScalaSessionFlash):

> "There is no technical timeout for the Session. It expires when the user closes the web browser. If you need a functional timeout for a specific application, just store a timestamp into the user Session and use it however your application needs (e.g. for a maximum session duration, maxmimum inactivity duration, etc.)."

So, it's up to you to implement it as you want it.

I guess, but I am not talking for the play developers, that this is to enforce stateless requests on the server side.